# R shiny output to external file

Tags: r, shiny

I'm running a shiny app from the command line and I would like to redirect shiny output to an external file like for example logs.txt instead of console output:

```
"Loading required package: shiny
Warning: package ‘shiny’ was built under R version 3.2.4
(...)
Failed with error:  ‘Package ‘shiny’ version 0.13.1 cannot be unloaded’

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3333" > logs.txt
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003717168-Shiny-Server-Error-Logs

Answer (score 2):

You can maybe have something like this, it will create a file in the working directory and all the messages will be written into it

```
#Set up writing
con <- file("shiny.log")
sink(con, append=TRUE)
sink(con, append=TRUE, type="message")

library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel()
)

server <- function(input,output,session){
  message(paste0("Logged in at ", Sys.time()))
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: But how do you close the connection afterwards?